# OpenSSL with C#

Tags: c#, openssl, ssl-certificate

i am trying to write a program in C# through which i could be able to retrieve SSL Certificate Subject of a URL. For this purpose i have to used OpenSSL with TCP port, i have tried too many functions but not found any solution.
I  have written the following code:

```
 try {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();

        var cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
        var subject = cert.Subject.ToString();
        txt.Text = subject;
        txt.Text = txt.Text + "<br>" + cert.Issuer;
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        txt.Text = exe.ToString();
    }
```

This code returns me the correct result according to my requirement but it is not on OpenSSL.

I have found the following code which is the perfect for my requirement but it is in c language where i need the same in C#.

```
http://fm4dd.com/openssl/sslconnect.htm
```

Any help be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Why do you need to go through OpenSSL?  Can't you get the same information through the .NET APIs?  It seems like you are going through some extra effort that shouldn't be needed.  OpenSSL is a C library.  To use it you either need to find a PInvoke library or write one yourself.

Comment: Basically i need to do it in c# with asp.net and also i know that there are too many helping materials on dot net APIs but my client are requesting me to do this with OpenSSL.

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net to see if that can help you.  Basically I would start hunting for a .NET wrapper library for OpenSSL.

Comment: Its not really clear what you are trying to do with OpenSSL and what the problem is when using OpenSSL. Maybe you should browse some of the results from [openssl "c#" site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+"c%23"+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Bouncy Castle is a better option in C# but this kind of question is not welcome at SO.

Comment: I Just changed the client idea and now i am rocking with C#... thank you all, i have voted you all guys by spending your precious time and your valuable comments and suggestions regarding OpenSSL. Thanks again.